# How to add css to a input field without id or class?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I need to add css to input field.

Using this `npm package material-ui-search-bar` in react app.

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" id="undefined-Search-undefined-33442" value="sdfsfsfd" style="padding: 0px; position: relative; width: 100%; border: none; outline: none; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); cursor: inherit; font: inherit; opacity: 1; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); height: 100%;">
```

Tried these but it doesn't work :

```
input {
  color: white
}
```

and this, but its not working.

```
input[type=text] {
  color: white;
}
```

I need the input text to be in white color.

Comment: this should work maybe `material-ui-search-bar` is overriding styles did you check in elements tab your styles are not getting overridden ?

Comment: So do I need to use important! here ?

Comment: That may work just give it a try.

Comment: it will work but not a good practice.

Dose `material-ui-search-bar` uses inline styles or class?

Comment: Yes but it doesn't have a way to edit input field

Comment: `material-ui-search-bar` uses `@material-ui/core/Input` here you can check style override is possible https://material-ui.com/api/input/. Apart from props required by `search-input` all other props passed to the input component check here - https://github.com/TeamWertarbyte/material-ui-search-bar/blob/5a5b12b4cc662ae93e22d87c7faacbebbf43e3c5/src/components/SearchBar/SearchBar.js#L157

If you check https://material-ui.com/api/input/ docs you'll find the solution.

Comment: `color` is already specified inline on the text element, are you able to edit that and change `color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);` to `color: white;`? Otherwise no, other than setting it there, there is no way to change the CSS without an ID or a class

Comment: This  'color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);'  change to 'color: rgba(255,255,255,1.0);'